# Arduino and parsing SMS message content into variables and strings

Tags: parsing, sms, arduino

I am wondering how to use sms messages to send variables and chars to an Arduino. I guess I would need to use some separators and some sort of parsing code. Something like this?
The SMS message can look however I need it to. But here is what I was thinking.

1,var1:int,var2:int,var3:int,var4:int,var5:int
2,var1|char,var1i:int,var2|char,var2i:int,var3|char,var3i:int,var4|char,var4i:int

My thinking is if I could use the initial number to run different parsing to extract the variables and strings and whatnot.

I'm using the SIM900.h library and I can get the SMS message into a char like this I just have no idea where to go with the parsing function :-|

```
 SMSpos = sms.IsSMSPresent(SMS_UNREAD);
   if(SMSpos >= 1){

     SMSmessage[0] = '\0';
     sms.GetSMS(SMSpos,number,SMSmessage,180);
     sms.DeleteSMS(SMSpos);
     SMSpos = 0;
   }
```

Comment: Have you `Serial.print()`ed the content of the SMS to see how it looks like? And if so, how does it look like?

Comment: I can make the SMS look however I need to in order to parse it successfully with the arduino

Comment: Parsing is not a magical thing, you need to know the pattern of the message to parse it. Is it JSON? is it XML? Show us an example and we'll think of a way of parsing it.

Comment: There is no pattern yet. I am creating the text message from SMSGlobal HTTP API. So I can generate the message in whatever format is needed for the parsing to work. Completely open to suggestions on the pattern and delimiter method, I've shown a couple of examples in my original post though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send text, you can go with JSON. It's easy to write and easy to parse, even on Arduino, with libraries like aJson (https://github.com/interactive-matter/aJson).

Comment: How can I send JSON in a SMS though?

Comment: so an sms with two values one a string and one a int could be sent something like this?
{"MSG":"1","format":{"val1":1234,"string1":"hello"}}
this would present inside MSG 1 the values val1=1234 and string1=hello ?

Comment: Awesome! that works a treat. Or at least with some initial testing! Thanks mate!